# how to generate barcodes with this python format?

Tags: python-3.x, barcode

I have come to ask a little question, I installed some python modules to generate barcodes(python-barcode, pybarcode, treepoem, PyUPC-EAN etc.), however this image is generated:

image1:

[image: 1.png]

I want is to know if there is some way or other module that generates the codes in this way:

image2:

[image: 2.jpg]

this is the code is the one I used for image 1:

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

def genUPCA(code,coding,name):
    cod = barcode.get(code, coding, writer=ImageWriter())
    filename = cod.save(name)

genUPCA('upca', '123456789102', 'image')
```

**EDIT**

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals;
    import upcean

    barcode = upcean.oopfuncs.barcode('upce', '01234567')
    print(barcode.validate_checksum())
    barcode.validate_create_barcode("./IMAGE.png", 4)
```

output: False

**eror:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oo.DESKTOP-8BMSU73\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\upcean\barcodes\codabar.py", line 33, in create_codabar_barcode
    pil_ver = Image.PILLOW_VERSION;
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'PILLOW_VERSION'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Tareas\T.py", line 12, in <module>
    image = upcean.oopfuncs.barcode("codabar", "A1234567890B").draw_barcode(2)
  File "C:\Users\oo.DESKTOP-8BMSU73\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\upcean\oopfuncs\oopfuncs.py", line 115, in draw_barcode
    return upcean.barcodes.draw_barcode(self.type, self.code, size, (self.hidesn, self.hidecd, self.hidetext), self.barheight, self.textxy, (self.barcolor, self.textcolor, self.bgcolor));
  File "C:\Users\oo.DESKTOP-8BMSU73\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\upcean\barcodes\shortcuts.py", line 29, in draw_barcode
    return create_barcode(bctype,upc,None,resize,hideinfo,barheight,textxy,barcolor);
  File "C:\Users\oo.DESKTOP-8BMSU73\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\upcean\barcodes\shortcuts.py", line 24, in create_barcode
    return getattr(upcean.barcodes.barcode, "create_"+bctype+"_barcode")(upc,outfile,resize,hideinfo,barheight,textxy,barcolor);
  File "C:\Users\oo.DESKTOP-8BMSU73\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\upcean\barcodes\codabar.py", line 38, in create_codabar_barcode
    pil_ver = Image.VERSION;
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'VERSION'
```

Comment: Are you looking for EAN-13 format barcode?

Comment: Read up on [python-barcode - Creating barcodes as Image](https://python-barcode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/barcode.html#creating-barcodes-as-image)

Comment: no, i just want to know if there is a way to print the code in the image like this in image 2.

Comment: I wanted to know if the printing of the code to the image had to do with the dependencies that they use as a pillow

Comment: According the docu: ***Pillow is required for exporting images (png, jpg), although not for SVGs.***

Comment: understood, then pillow has some function to print the image1 the same as the image2

Comment: if the code shown in image 1 is generated, but I want it as image2

Comment: of course, I need to generate code upc-a and upc-e, those are the types I want to generate, it doesn't matter if python-barcode can't, any module always and when it generates the codes like image 2

Comment: Read [python-barcode/issues/74](https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/issues/74) does not support such positioning format.

Comment: and which modules are compatible with this "standard" format

Comment: It seems all modules, except `UPC-EAN` are based at `python-barcode`. I can't run `UPC-EAN` but according the source [barcodes/ean13.py](https://github.com/GameMaker2k/PyUPC-EAN/blob/master/upcean/barcodes/ean13.py) it supports two `barheight=(48, 54)`. Give this a try.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't know how to run pyUPC-EAN. Could you please show me an example of how to generate a code with this module, because when I run it it gave me the error that pillow_version does not exist (I have pillow 7.0.0)

Comment: i changed for PIL.__version__;

Comment: Run with this [upc-example.py](https://github.com/GameMaker2k/PyUPC-EAN/blob/master/examples/upc-example.py) again

Comment: finally printed the image in the edition of this question, but pixelated

Comment: there is a function for you to create a certain size

Comment: Play with the `size=1` argument in `.validate_create_barcode(..., 1)

Comment: the `validate_create_code()` won't let me create an upc-a code if I don't put a special name that has the code. I need the keys to generate the image, I think it would be the last

Comment: `barcode.validate_create_barcode("./1234567890128.png)`for some reason if I change this the image does not generate.

Comment: Image.jpg o upcimage.jpg,anyone can vary according to what the user wants to put

Comment: I just want to generate code upc-a and upc-e nothing else

Comment: The filename does not distinguish between different barcode types. These are defined withe the first argument at: `.barcode('upca', ...`. The filename extension, e.g **.png**, defines which image file type get writen. BTW, using **.jpg** is a bad option  and can lead to bad image quality.

Comment: the upc-a receives 12 numbers and the upc-e 8

Comment: Try my correct UPC: `01234565`

Comment: ***I can't put any number***: Rereading the wiki it points out that only **6-digits** are relevant. The first digit is always **0** or **1** and the last digit is the checksum

Comment: I understand, and the upc-a is the same

Comment: well I think that would be all, thanks bro for the help, I will study how the codes work to create them well, thanks once again for your attention and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reference**:

- [PyUPC-EAN](https://github.com/GameMaker2k/PyUPC-EAN)
- [Universal_Product_Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code)

---

```
import upcean


class UPC(upcean.oopfuncs.barcode):
    def __init__(self, _type, filename):
        super().__init__(_type)
        self.filename = f'{filename}.png'
        self._digits = {'upca': 12, 'upce': 8}.get(_type, None)

    def validate_create_barcode(self, upc):
        self.code = upc
        checksum = upc[-1]

        if len(upc) < self._digits:
            checksum = self.validate_checksum()
            if checksum:
                self.code += checksum
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'Invalid upc {self.code}!')
        else:
            valid = self.validate_checksum()
            if not valid:
                raise ValueError(f'Invalid upc {self.code}, validate checksum failed!')

        print(f'.validate_create_barcode({self.filename}, {self.code}, checksum={checksum})')
        super().validate_create_barcode(self.filename, size=2)


class UPC_A(UPC):
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        if filename is None:
            filename =  'upc-a'
        super().__init__('upca', filename)

class UPC_E(UPC):
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        if filename is None:
            filename =  'upc-e'
        super().__init__('upce', filename)
```

> **Usage**:

[image]
[image]

```
upca = UPC_A()
for upc in ('042100005264', '04210000526'):
    upca.validate_create_barcode(upc)

upce = UPC_E()
for upc in ('06543217', '0654321'):
    upca.validate_create_barcode(upc)
```

> **Output**:
>   .validate_create_barcode(upc-a.png, 042100005264, checksum=4)
>   .validate_create_barcode(upc-a.png, 042100005264, checksum=4)
>
> .validate_create_barcode(upc-e.png, 06543217, checksum=7)
>   .validate_create_barcode(upc-e.png, 06543217, checksum=7)